# Efficient way to query or set the volume name of an ext3 partition under Linux?

Tags: linux, volume, ext3

Through a bit of digging, I've discovered how to set and get the volume name of an ext3 partition on my Linux box:

## set the volume label

tune2fs -L MY-NEW-NAME /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0-part1

## get the volume's current level

dumpe2fs -h /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0-part1 | grep 'volume name'

Those work fine, but I have several questions:

1) Are those commands the best way to set/get the volume name?  Or is there an easier method that I don't know about?

2) How likely is changing a volume's label to break something?  i.e. does a standard Linux system rely on volumes having certain names?  Or can I rename volumes to any names I like, without causing problems?

3) At some point I would like to include in my program a GUI interface to the above functionality.  One way to do that would be to have my program execute the above shell commands (via system() or whatever), but that seems a bit clunky and heavyweight... are there direct functions that I can call to do the same thing?  If so, what are they?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What about e2label?
2) The 'mount' command can identify devices via their label, so changing a label could break something inside /etc/fstab.. Anyway normally they aren't used. (At least on Ubuntu and Fedora IIRC)
3) What language are you using? Anyway, it looks like [e2label](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=blob;f=misc/e2label.c;h=e96101aef59455143abccfc5b6c1dfec8d255dda;hb=master) doesn't use any particular API.. It reads and writes to the device directly

Comment: The kernel doesn't care at all, but init scripts and mount (fstab) might.

Comment: /sbin/vol_id --label <device>   - works on other filesystems than extN as well.

Comment: To get the label I use `blkid -s LABEL <device>`, that seems quite nice.